# How do I pass in a parameter name into a function as an argument in python?

Tags: python, function, arguments, arcgis, esri

How do I pass in a parameter name into a function as an argument?

```
def edit_features_retry(editType,data):
    AGOLlayer.edit_features(editType=data)

edit_features_retry("adds", datalayer)
```

error:

```
TypeError: edit_features() got an unexpected keyword argument 'editType'
```

If I do it this way as a string:

```
def edit_features_retry(editType,data):
    AGOLlayer.edit_features(editType=data)

edit_features_retry(adds, datalayer)
```

error:

```
NameError: name 'adds' is not defined
```

Comment: `edit_features(**{editType: data})`

Comment: That worked. So passing it in as a Dict? what does the asterisks do?

Comment: The "double-splat" unpacks the dictionary into function arguments, exactly like how you want. See my [full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78105431/9816919). Note that the dictionary only exists temporarily, and is not actually passed into the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [dictionary unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments).

Here's a simple example:

```py
def f(a = 1, b = 2):
  print(f"{a = }, {b = }")

f(b=5)  # output: "a = 1, b = 5"

kwargs = {"b": 5}
f(**kwargs)  # output: "a = 1, b = 5"
```

Which can be applied to your scenario:

```py
def edit_features_retry(editType, data):
    AGOLlayer.edit_features(**{editType: data})

edit_features_retry("adds", datalayer)
```

Comment: @ajd018 Suggested reading: [4.8. More on Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions) in the Python tutorial.